# How to reference only some parts of MultiIndex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This questions have two stages.

I have a `MultiIndex`, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
     'colour': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'],
     'amount': [28.1, 5.6, 43.6, 13.3, 4.1, 27.6, 19.7, 37.5, 26.7, 73.7, 94.4, 77.5],
     'scalar': [3.4, 2.8, 3.4, 1.7, 2.2, 0.8, 1.9, 0.3, 2.4, 0.2, 0.5, 1.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index(['category', 'colour'], inplace=True)
```

The result being:

```
                 amount  scalar
category colour                
a        red       28.1     3.4
         blue       5.6     2.8
         green     43.6     3.4
         orange    13.3     1.7
b        red        4.1     2.2
         blue      27.6     0.8
         green     19.7     1.9
         orange    37.5     0.3
c        red       26.7     2.4
         blue      73.7     0.2
         green     94.4     0.5
         orange    77.5     1.5
```

**Stage 1**

I want to select all the rows with `colour` as `green`, regardless of the `category`. I'm sure it's super simple, but can't work it out.

The result should look like:

```
                 amount  scalar
category colour                
a        green     43.6     3.4
b        green     19.7     1.9
c        green     94.4     0.5
```

**Stage 2**
Multiply all `amount` values by 10 for all `green` rows.

Result would be:

```
                 amount  scalar
category colour                
a        red       28.1     3.4
         blue       5.6     2.8
         green    436.0     3.4
         orange    13.3     1.7
b        red        4.1     2.2
         blue      27.6     0.8
         green    197.0     1.9
         orange    37.5     0.3
c        red       26.7     2.4
         blue      73.7     0.2
         green    944.0     0.5
         orange    77.5     1.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will using `IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'green'],:]
Out[86]: 
                 amount  scalar
category colour                
a        green     43.6     3.4
b        green     19.7     1.9
c        green     94.4     0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.xs('green', level='colour', drop_level=False)
                 amount  scalar
category colour
a        green     43.6     3.4
b        green     19.7     1.9
c        green     94.4     0.5
```

Comment: Hello @Tom Ron, this seem like the best way to do it, answering the question as I had asked it. I've updated the questions to clarify and include what I'm aiming for - that is to edit the `amount` values for only `green` rows. Can this be used for that?

Answer (score 2):

Using `query` here

---

```
df.query('colour == "green"')
```

```
                 amount  scalar
category colour
a        green     43.6     3.4
b        green     19.7     1.9
c        green     94.4     0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(level=1) =='green']
```

Output:

```
                    amount  scalar
category    colour      
a           green   43.6    3.4
b           green   19.7    1.9
c           green   94.4    0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!